# aws elastic beanstalk deploys my app but on next deployments throws an error

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, npm, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm new to aws beanstalk and this issue confuses me so much.

1. First I create eb application and use their sample app (node v16)
2. I download `eb cli`
3. I create a nextjs app using `npx create-next-app@latest --typescript`
4. I create a file `.ebignore` with a line `/node_modules`
5. I run `npm run build` and then test that it works with `npm run start`
6. I run `eb init` and select my eb sample app, then I run `eb deploy`

On the first deploy it does everything correctly and my app is deployed.

However, I then make a small text change run `npm run build` and then `eb deploy`
and on my second tries I get errors:

```
2022-12-30 15:25:21    INFO    Environment update is starting.      
2022-12-30 15:25:26    INFO    Deploying new version to instance(s).
2022-12-30 15:25:29    INFO    Instance deployment: You didn't specify a Node.js version in the 'package.json' file in your source bundle. The deployment didn't install a specific Node.js version.
2022-12-30 15:25:46    ERROR   Instance deployment: 'npm' failed to install dependencies that you defined in 'package.json'. For details, see 'eb-engine.log'. The deployment failed.
2022-12-30 15:25:46    ERROR   Instance deployment failed. For details, see 'eb-engine.log'.
2022-12-30 15:25:49    ERROR   [Instance: i-08b3d32eff44fb29b] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: Engine 
execution has encountered an error..
2022-12-30 15:25:49    INFO    Command execution completed on all instances. Summary: [Successful: 0, Failed: 1].        
2022-12-30 15:25:49    ERROR   Unsuccessful command execution on instance id(s) 'i-08b3d32eff44fb29b'. Aborting the operation.
2022-12-30 15:25:49    ERROR   Failed to deploy application.
```

When I request logs for `eb-engine.log` I get:

```
2022/12/30 15:25:30.600993 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c npm --production install
2022/12/30 15:25:46.171460 [INFO] npm WARN config production Use `--omit=dev` instead.
npm ERR! code ENOMEM
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! errno -12
npm ERR! spawn ENOMEM

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2022-12-30T15_25_30_951Z-debug-0.log

2022/12/30 15:25:46.171859 [ERROR] An error occurred during execution of command [app-deploy] - [Use NPM to install dependencies]. Stop running the command. Error: Command /bin/sh -c npm --production install failed with error exit status 244. Stderr:npm WARN config production Use `--omit=dev` instead.
npm ERR! code ENOMEM
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! errno -12
npm ERR! spawn ENOMEM

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2022-12-30T15_25_30_951Z-debug-0.log
 

2022/12/30 15:25:46.171867 [INFO] Executing cleanup logic
2022/12/30 15:25:46.171975 [INFO] CommandService Response: {"status":"FAILURE","api_version":"1.0","results":[{"status":"FAILURE","msg":"Engine execution has encountered an error.","returncode":1,"events":[{"msg":"Instance deployment: You didn't specify a Node.js version in the 'package.json' file in your source bundle. The deployment didn't install a specific Node.js version.","timestamp":1672413929779,"severity":"INFO"},{"msg":"Instance deployment: 'npm' failed to install dependencies that you defined in 'package.json'. For details, see 'eb-engine.log'. The deployment failed.","timestamp":1672413946171,"severity":"ERROR"},{"msg":"Instance deployment failed. For details, see 'eb-engine.log'.","timestamp":1672413946171,"severity":"ERROR"}]}]}

2022/12/30 15:25:46.174080 [INFO] Platform Engine finished execution on command: app-deploy
```

```
[ERROR] An error occurred during execution of command [app-deploy] - [Use NPM to install dependencies]. Stop running the command. Error: Command /bin/sh -c npm --production install failed with error exit status 244. Stderr:npm WARN config production Use `--omit=dev` instead.
```

No idea why it deploys it first time but then errors on my other attempts.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that Elastic Beanstalk ran out of memory when running `npm install`.

Changing configuration to `t2.large`, running `eb deploy` and then changing configuration back to `t2.micro` & `t2.small` fixed this.

Comment: sorry I didn't get it; I understand that it's a matter of memory so I expected increasing the size would solve it, but why changing it back to smaller size get it to work?

Comment: @Mee I think what they are saying is that increasing the size and deploying is what actually made it work. And then they added the note that they also changed the configuration back which seems unrelated (but good to know for people that don't want to pay extra).